# Benes (Fat Tree) Network for number of inputs/outputs that is not 2^n

Tags: computer-networks, network-topology

I was reading about Benes Network construction in this [book](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=995703).
Their construction is easy for a number of inputs and outputs that is an exponent of two.

However it seems to me that for a number of i/o that falls between $2^{n}$ and $2^{(n+1)}$ one has to construct a network with $2^{(n+1)}$ ports and leave many unattached, which is wasteful. 
Is there a synthesis method for Benes networks or maybe an alternative topology that has the same properties (re-arrangeable not blocking) for arbitrary number of I/O?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, Benes Network can be written in terms of Butterfly and reverse Butterfly. 
http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~ranade/408/archive/benes.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This paper [1] presents a method to construct arbitrarily sized benes networks using a recursive approach.

1. [Arbitrary Size Benes Networks](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~melhem/research/parallel/papers/parlet.pdf) by Chihming Chang and Rami Melhem in *Parallel Processing Letters*, Volume 7, 1997

Answer (score 3):

Wasting ports to achieve an exact number of terminals is a common attribute of staged networks (butterfly, benes, folded-clos, etc.). The mesh, torus, and [flattened butterfly](http://bnrg.cs.berkeley.edu/~kubitron/courses/cs258-S08/handouts/papers/ISCA_FBFLY.pdf) topologies are a bit better because each dimension can have a different width, but this results in having uneven bisection bandwidth along each dimensional cut. The [HyperX](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs6810/HyperX-SC09.pdf) topology is a generalization of the flattened butterfly that allows each dimension to be configured independently in terms of width and weight (number of links connecting each pair of routers). The paper describes an algorithm to find the "optimal" configuration given a requirement for system size, bisection bandwidth, and router radix. An implementation of this algorithm is [here](https://github.com/nicmcd/hyperxsearch). Given the requirements, it finds a satisfactory topology configuration that minimize cost (like wasted ports).